# Instagram OAuth login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, instagram

I would like to build an app for Instagram login. The problem is that i don't know how to initialize connection with instagram client id. I had done this with OAuth.initialize(), but it doesn't work. I am recieving 'OAuthException'.

My code so far:

```
 return {
    initialize: function() {
        //initialize OAuth.io with public key of the application
        OAuth.initialize('e6u0TKccWPGCnAqheXQYg76Vf2M', {cache:true});
        authorizationResult = OAuth.create('instagram');
        console.log(authorizationResult);
    },
    isReady: function() {
        return (authorizationResult);
    },
    connectInstagram: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        OAuth.popup('instagram', {cache:true}, function(error, result) { 
            if (!error) {
                authorizationResult = result;
                deferred.resolve();
                console.log('case');

            } else {
              console.log('case2');
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    },
    clearCache: function() {
        OAuth.clearCache('instagram');
        authorizationResult = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the only acceptable argument for OAuth.initialize is "public key".
Remove the second parameter.